# Connect 2 Networks and restrict acces

Tags: networking, router, firewall, routing

The Setting:

2 apartments where each has it's own internet connection over an AVM Fritz!Box. I'd like to connect both apartments with a network cable.

In apartment 1 is a NAS wich should be accesible from apartment 2 but nothing else.

As a bonus, it would be nice to use both internetconnections over night to speed up download. It would be sufficient if apartment 1 can acces the internetconnection of apartment 2 overnigt.

Which Router can I use to connect both networks? The subnet seperation/firewalling is a must.

Here is a picture to clarify what I have in mind:

[image]

Is the setup possible with two Fritz!Box router or do I need a firewall router/switch in between?

Comment: Are you asking for shopping advice?

Comment: I'm not sure - the most consumer products can't do that as far as I know... If I know how to search for the options I need that would help too. I do know what I search but not to do the search. Maybe it is a shopping advice.